# Looping over files of folder and add as attachment

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, directory

I have a folder which will contain `.pdf` and `.xls` but the numbers will vary from time to time and this is the main issue for me.Now as per my requirement i have to read the location of both of these types of files and add as attachment into my smtp mail code like this ..

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(sourceDir);
mail.Attachments.Add(att);
```

This is for the one file attachment .How to add all as described above as attachement in this code..
Please help me..

Comment: Loop thru `Directory.GetFiles()` looking for the correct extension  `mail.Attachments.Add`'ing each match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// Get all the files in the sourceDir
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"sourceDir");

// Get the files that their extension are either pdf of xls. 
var files = filePaths.Where(filePath => Path.GetExtension(filePath).Contains(".pdf") 
                                     || Path.GetExtension(filePath).Contains(".xls"));

// Loop through the files enumeration and attach each file in the mail.
foreach(var file in files)
{
    var attachment = new Attachment(file);
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] fileNames  = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\myLocation", "*.xls", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
```

Will retreive the file names with a given pattern ina  given directory. You can load them from the source path and attach them to your Mail.

Edit: forgot .ToArray()